# Making Date Field “Required” in SharePoint 2013 List breaks custom List Form Validation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I have a custom new form for SharePoint 2013 List which has multiple required field and when I click on Submit, validation of form works fine and if any mandatory field is blank,it shows error in red "You must specify a value for this required field."

Issue is If I mark DateTime field as mandatory then mandatory validation is not working properly.It is not validating all mandatory fields and showing message in red on submitting/adding new record. This is issue only when using custom form,not in default newform.aspx.

I saw [similar issue here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/37c49dfd-cd7d-4775-9aec-ebff658b6a4c/mandatory-date-field-validation-different-if-using-a-custom-form-why?forum=sharepointgeneral) but not proper answer why this is occuring and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Because, the system will check if the datetime field empty first, then check for others, if you set a value for this datetime field and check the save button, if other mandatory fields empty, they will also show the error message below the field.

As a workaround, we can set default value for the DateTime field in field settings.

[image]